# communication between agent and UI

Tags: windows-phone-8

i have 2 pages in my WP8 app, in the first one i search photos, on the second one i show the downloaded photos, when i click the button in order to find and download the photos, i want to search    the photos with a Background agent, there I want to write code using    Background Transfer Service but also, i want to update the progress of the photo while it is downloading on the UI.

How can I do it if I can't access the UI from the background agent? Is there any other way to do it?